# how to remove overspace/margin between childView and CardView

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using CardView **android.support.v7.widget.CardView** and trying to use LinearLayout as a childView but I suppose there is default margin , how can i remove the gap between LinearLayout and CardView;

[image]

Here you can see the gap or margin, guide me to fit this like match parent !here is sample code!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6sp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/lineDivider"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0.9dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0.9dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtNameTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="7dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="7dp"
                    android:paddingRight="7dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/disableTextColor"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Name:"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: post your xml code of this .. and remove this attribute android:layout_margin="6dp" for removing space

Comment: android:layout_margin="6dp" this is for parent you can say for outer space ..

Comment: code is right above mentioned full code could be complicated to understand  ,